# FB.Login then check status of App Auth

Tags: facebook

Is there any way I can, when a user isn't logged in to facebook, prompted them to login but then not ask them to authorize my app?

So, when they aren't logged in, I want to get them to log in, not authorize the app, then when they're logged in, check the authorize status of the app and if it's not authorized have then do something (register)?

Thanks

Comment: No. Either you have them connect to your app, or you’ll no absolutely nothing about them.

Comment: The trouble is, if I allow a person authorize the app without first registering (and by registering, I mean OAuth with additional fields) then I will miss essential information I need.

Comment: Hm, maybe you want to use the Registration plugin instead …? – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/